# How to get token with recaptcha enterprise Angular 8+

Tags: javascript, html, angular-cli, angular12, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm trying to implement recaptcha enterprise in angular 12, but documentation is not being clear, I implemented it in the class according to the documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-web-pages?hl=pt-br), but the method does not return the token in $event

```html
<form [formGroup]="partnerForm" (ngSubmit)="becomePartner($event)" #partnerFormEl="ngForm" method="POST"> 

<button id="demo-form" class="g-recaptcha"
            data-sitekey="6LeCCoYfAAA..."
            data-callback='becomePartner'
            data-action='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I need a light on this documentation, any example already implemented?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did yo manage to resolve. All the solution appear to be for V3 which is different than the enterprise version.